# Suppose $f(x)\geq 0$, and $\int_0^{+\infty} f^2(x)dx$ is convergent. Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\int_0^x e^t f(t) dt}{e^x}=0.$

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

Suppose $f(x)\geq 0$, and $\int_0^{+\infty} f^2(x)dx$ is convergent. Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\int_0^x e^t f(t) dt}{e^x}=0.$

Notice that we are not given the continuity of $f(x)$. Hence L' Hospital's rule can  not work here. If we consider apply AM-GM inequality, we obtain
$$e^{x}f(x)\leq \frac{f^2(x)+e^{2x}}{2},$$ where $\int_0^{+\infty} f^2(x)dx<+\infty$ but $\int_0^{\infty} e^{2t}=+\infty$, which gives nothing helpful.

How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the result is $0$?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar This would be the result if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Not sure. The problem is what someone else asked me. Do you have a conterexample? @ArchisWelankar

Comment: @eranreches Can we infer $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$ from the assumption conditions?

Comment: @mengdie1982: No, not even for a continuous function. Think of a function which is zero except for triangular “spikes” with height $1$ and area $1/n$ at $x=n \in \Bbb N$. – And unless I am mistaken, that is a counter-example for your claim as well.

Comment: Yeah, @MartinR is right. Just reviewed my calculus notes.

Comment: So even if we take a continuous $f$ without a limit at infinity, then you can use L'Hospital's and the limit in question (which is exactly the limit of $f$ at infinity) doesn't exist.

Comment: @MartinR I do not grasp you very well. How to draw your triangle at a point?

Comment: @MartinR The result seems to be true. Can you take  a look at my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $\Delta $ such that $\int_{\Delta} ^{\infty} f(x)^{2}dx <\epsilon^{2}$. By C-S inequality we have $|\int_{\Delta} ^{x} e^{t}f(t)dt| \leq \epsilon (\int_{\Delta} ^{x} e^{2t}dt)^{1/2}=\epsilon (\frac {e^{2x}-e^{2\Delta}} 2)^{1/2}$.  Hence $|\frac {\int_{\Delta} ^{x} e^{t}f(t)dt} {e^{x}}| <\epsilon 2^{-1/2}$.  Next note that $\frac {\int_0^{\Delta}  e^{t}f(t)dt} {e^{x}} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Combining these two we get the result.

Comment: Looks good.....

Comment: Thanks for your help. I complete the proof according to your hint, please check it.

Comment: Yet another time you have copied my answer and shown it as your answer. **This is highly immoral**. You should say that your answer is an expansion of my answer. Until you apologize I will not say whether your answer is correct or not.

Comment: I'm sorry. There may be a misunderstanding here. Since your solution is a bit brief, some details lacks. I just wonder whether what I write is what you think or not. I have claimed "the proof is according to you".

Comment: Your answer is fine. Make it a point from now on to give credit to the answerer. Also, it is better to put your answer within the question box instead of posting it as  a separate answer. That is what others are doing.

Answer (score 1):

## A proof from Kavi Rama Murthyk

Since $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}f^2(x)dx$ is convergent，by Cauchy's convergence test, we have
$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \xi>0,\forall x>\xi ~~~s.t.~~~ \int_{\xi}^{x} f^2(t)dt< 2\varepsilon^2.$$
Thus，as per Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality，we obtain
$$\int_{\xi}^x e^t f(t)dt \leq \left(\int_{\xi}^x f^2(t)dt \cdot \int_{\xi}^x e^{2t}dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}< \left(2\varepsilon^2 \int_{\xi}^x e^{2t}dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\varepsilon \left(e^{2x}-e^{2\xi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}},$$
which implies
$$\frac{\int_{\xi}^x e^t f(t)dt}{e^x}\leq \varepsilon \left(1-e^{\frac{\xi}{x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \varepsilon$$
holds for all $x>\xi$. Therefore， taking the limits of both sides as $x \to +\infty$, we have
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\int_{\xi}^x e^t f(t)dt}{e^x}\leq \varepsilon.\tag{1}$$
Meanwihle, notice that，for the fixed $\xi$,
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\int_0^\xi e^t f(t)dt}{e^x}=0.\tag{2}$$
$(1)$ plus $(2)$, we obtain
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\int_0^x e^t f(t)dt}{e^x}\leq\varepsilon,$$
by the arbitariness of $\varepsilon>0$，which implies
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\int_0^x e^t f(t)dt}{e^x}=0.$$